# JBAS014360: EJB 3.1 FR 4.3.14.1 concurrent access timeout on org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext

Tags: java, ejb, jboss7.x, seam2

I'm doing a migration to JBoss AS 7.1 and Seam 2.3, but having some issues with `JBAS014360: EJB 3.1 FR 4.3.14.1 concurrent access timeout on org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext`

Here is my action class:

```
@Name("myAction")
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
public class MyAction implements java.io.Serializable {
    @In(create = true)
    private MyService myService;

    @In(required = false)
    @Out(required = true)
    private User user;

    @In(required = false)
    @Out(required = false)
    private Acquisition acquisition;

    @Begin(join = true)
    @Create
    public void init() {
       // more code
         acquisition = myService.getNext(user);
    }

    public void saveHistory() {
       myService.saveHistory(acquisition, user);
    }
}
```

and a service class.

```
@Stateless
@Name("myService")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    @In(create = true)
    private EntityManager em;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public Acquisition getNext(User user){
      // em.createNamedQuery(...);
      // acquisition.update(user);
      // em.flush();
      // return acquisition
   }

   @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
   public Acquisition saveHistory(Acquisition acquisition,User user){
     history = createHistoryObject(...);
     acquisition.getHistories().add(history);
     return acquisition;
   }
}
```

`getNext(User user)` method is called from the `init()` block and it causes the exception.

`saveHistory(...)` method is called from the xhtml page and works as expected.

What's wrong with the `init()` block? Some change in EJB 3.1 or in Seam 2.3?

Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way for this to work.

If I just put the

```
@In(create = true)
private EntityManager em;
```

in `MyAction.class` and nothing else, then everything works.

Still looking for explanation of this behavior.

Any ideas?